# Hidden Chrome WIndows using Python Selenium whataspp bot

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

Im trying to do a whatsapp bot with python and selenium. I could do it, but what I want now, is that the process run in background. I dont want to see the windows browser.

The problem I have is that i cant set these options at the same time:

```
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=./User_Data') #keep whatsapp logged - no need to sacan QR-Code
options.add_argument("--headless")   #hide browser
```

this is the error:

**> DevTools listening on

> ws://127.0.0.1:54257/devtools/browser/b5c648c5-3922-4fc3-8200-d0b3570a4d2f
>   [0504/103817.555:ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(292)] Error writing
>   DevTools active port to file
>   [0504/103817.556:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(81)] Failed to create
>   directory: ./User_Data\Default\Code Cache\js
>   [0504/103817.556:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(81)] Failed to create
>   directory: ./User_Data\Default\Code Cache\wasm
>   [0504/103817.559:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
>   [0504/103817.567:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(81)] Failed to create
>   directory: ./User_Data\Default\Code Cache\js
>   [0504/103817.567:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(81)] Failed to create
>   directory: ./User_Data\Default\Code Cache\wasm
>   [0504/103817.568:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(606)] Shader Cache
>   Creation failed: -2
>   [0504/103817.569:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(758)] Simple Cache
>   Backend: wrong file structure on disk: 1 path:
>   ./User_Data\Default\Code Cache\js
>   [0504/103817.569:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(758)] Simple Cache
>   Backend: wrong file structure on disk: 1 path:
>   ./User_Data\Default\Code Cache\wasm
>   [0504/103817.572:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(81)] Failed to create
>   directory: ./User_Data\Default\Code Cache\js
>   [0504/103817.573:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(81)] Failed to create
>   directory: ./User_Data\Default\Code Cache\wasm
>   [0504/103817.588:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(81)] Failed to create
>   directory: ./User_Data\Default\Code Cache\wasm
>   [0504/103817.588:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(81)] Failed to create
>   directory: ./User_Data\Default\Code Cache\js
>   [0504/103817.592:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(758)] Simple Cache
>   Backend: wrong file structure on disk: 1 path:
>   ./User_Data\Default\Code Cache\wasm
>   [0504/103817.592:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(758)] Simple Cache
>   Backend: wrong file structure on disk: 1 path:
>   ./User_Data\Default\Code Cache\js
>   [0504/103817.603:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
>   [0504/103817.606:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache**

Is there any way to do this...

this is the code:

```
from  selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=./User_Data')
options.add_argument("--headless")  

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
```